# How can I make all apps use the same theme in Gnome 42 on Fedora?

Tags: gnome-shell, theme, window-decorations

After a fresh installation, not all preinstalled apps seem to be using the same theme. And changing the theme seems to only change it for some.

How the window buttons of the file manager look:

[image: File manager]

How the buttons of the settings app look:

[image: Settings]

I don't have many options in Gnome Tweaks tool (none that references themes):

[image: Gnome tweaks]

The only option that affects the window buttons seems to be the "Legacy applications" one, but it doesn't affect either one of the mentioned two; however it does affect the terminal for example.

How can I set them to look the same? If they all use different underlying theming mechanisms, can I at least install the same theme in all 3 different places to achieve the desired result?

I am Fedora Linux 36 Workstation Edition, GNOME version 42.3. I don't know if Wayland vs X11 makes a difference, but the issues are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answers, so, to whom it may concern, here is the solution.

Apparently, the theme on my second screenshot (the Settings app) is called Libawaita, and some apps who sport this theme out of the box on Gnome 42, are doing so because they are not themable by installing custom user themes, while other apps who "listen to the system theme" are sporting Adwaita by default.

Therefore, by installing the Libadwaita for all other apps, the look of all apps will be uniform. The theme and installation instructions can be found [on Github](https://github.com/lassekongo83/adw-gtk3).